# Finding duplications in a List of Lists

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I've got a list of lists of an object having properties (let's say a name and a value).

I'd like to find and remove the duplicated lists if it's a part of another list - their order does matter.

Example in a pseudocode (I'll present it as a list of strings to make it easier):

```
List<List<String>>  = [
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"], 
["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
["5", "6", "7", "8"],
["7", "8"]
]
```

in this case, I'd like to remove shorter lists because they are part of the longer/most extended list.

My classes can be described like that:

```
public static class MyObjectBig {
    private String startElem;
    private String endElem;
    private List<MyObjectOne> list;
    
    // constructors, getters, etc.
}

public static class MyObjectOne {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    // constructors, getters, etc.
}
```

The large lists are massive - like 21,000 elements, and the small lists are most at 20 elements, usually ~10.

I've got a couple of ideas, like creating a `Map` of the having the first item as a *key* and all list as a value. Then iterating over all items checking if it exists in it if it does, then checking the next items. But that's very slow.

I'll appreciate any hints or ideas.

Comment: You could use the [`Collection.containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-) method to check if a list contains every item in another list. As for performance, you can play the odds a bit. Since bigger lists will have a higher chance of containing smaller lists, you can iterate through the smaller lists and check if the biggest lists contain them. Since these lists are big, you can also use `HashSet` instead of `List` so it doesn't have to loop through everything when checking if the bigger list contains the smaller one.

Comment: Are there any criteria how that would allow to determine that a *list* belongs to a particular *group of lists* (that share common elements) without looking at other lists? For instance, in your dummy example all the smaller lists share the same last element, is there something like that in real data?

Comment: @Jesse Unfortunately, I can't use containsAll()  as it's a list of objects. My object:
class MyObjectOne { String name, String value; } 
class MyObjectBig { String startElem, String endElem, List<MyObjectOne> list } 
List<MyObjectOne> thatsMyList <--- I'd like to remove duplicates described above from it. 

However, collecting all the 'names' and then iterating would help. Might be a good idea!

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko kind of. Every object in the outer list contains the name of the first and last element in the inner list. See my object in my previous comment above.

Comment: You can though. You would just have to override the equality members. In most cases you can have your IDE do this for you. Another approach, if you don't care about keeping it 2 dimensional, would just be to override the equality members (I believe it's just `getHashCode` in this case), then add every item in every list to a `HashSet`. This will remove duplicates and you'll be left with a nice list of distinct objects.

Comment: doh. Indeed! I'll try that @Jesse sounds like a brilliant idea. I think I've spent way too much time on that going in the wrong direction. I'll try to implement that - I'll keep you posted :) thank you!

Comment: Does `MyObjectOne` has a natural ordering (or potentially could have) and does the names `startElem` and `endElem` imply that all elements in the list `>=` that `startElem` and `<=` than `endElem`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko these are just strings, they aren't sorted in any way. They need to stay in the order of how they were inserted into the list.

Comment: What if 2nd sublist doesn't have a 7, but instead has a 9? Is the end result that the first 2 element are preserved, since neither is a subset of the other? In this case you end up with multiple elements repeated across both lists (3,4,5,6,8) - acceptable? If not then I don't understand the problem as you've presented it

Comment: @Michael that bit won't match the largest list, so should not be removed. Only exact matches counts.

Comment: @Jesse your hint with equals and hashCode helped me as well resolving the issue. Looks like I've been looking at my code way too long to spot the obvious stuff. Anyways. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `equals/hashCode` contract is properly implemented in the `MyObjectOne` you can define an auxiliary wrapper class which would hold a reference to the original `MyObjectBig` instance and maintain a `HashMap` of *map entries* containing *frequencies* of each `MyObjectOne` elements from the *original list* (so if there could be duplicated elements within a list, they would be taken into account during comparison).

That's how such wrapper class might look like:

```
public static class BigObjectWrapper {
    private MyObjectBig bigObject;
    private Map<MyObjectOne, Long> frequencies;
    private int listSize;
    private int mapSize;
    private boolean isDuplicate;
    
    public BigObjectWrapper(MyObjectBig bigObject) {
        this.bigObject = bigObject;
        this.frequencies = bigObject.getList().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(),
                Collectors.counting()
            ));
        
        this.listSize = bigObject.getList().size();
        this.mapSize = frequencies.size();
    }
    
    public boolean contains(BigObjectWrapper other) {
        if (listSize < other.listSize || mapSize < other.mapSize) return false;
        
        return containsAll(other.frequencies);
    }
    
    private boolean containsAll(Map<MyObjectOne, Long> otherFrequencies) {
        
        return otherFrequencies.entrySet().stream() // frequency of each element in other map less or equal to frequency of this element
            .allMatch(entry -> frequencies.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0L) >= entry.getValue());
    }
    
    public boolean isDuplicate() {
        return isDuplicate;
    }
    
    public void setDuplicate() {
        isDuplicate = true;
    }
    
    // getters, equals/hashCode implemented based on the size and set properties
}
```

Now, the algorithm can be implemented in the following steps:

- Create a list of wrapped objects.
- Compare each wrapper against others. If the wrapper has been already proven to be a duplicate, it would be skipped. Also, in cases when a wrapper object containing a smaller set would be compared against a wrapper object holding a greater set, the call would terminate immediately returning `false` (therefore there's no point in sorting the data).
- Generate a new list of `MyObjectBig` from wrapper objects that were not proven to be duplicates.

That's how implementation might look like:

```
List<MyObjectBig> source = List.of();
        
List<BigObjectWrapper> wrappers = source.stream()
    .map(BigObjectWrapper::new)
    .toList();
        
for (BigObjectWrapper wrapper : wrappers) {
    if (wrapper.isDuplicate()) continue;
    for (BigObjectWrapper next : wrappers) {
        if (next.isDuplicate()) continue;
        if (wrapper.contains(next)) next.setDuplicate();
    }
}
        
List<MyObjectBig> result = wrappers.stream()
    .filter(w -> !w.isDuplicate())
    .map(BigObjectWrapper::getBigObject)
    .toList();
```

***Note:** if you don't need to consider the case when one larger list can be a part of another larger list, then you can split the data into two parts. And then as the first step, check only smaller lists against the larger once, and as the second step, check the remained non-duplicated smaller lists against each other.*

Comment: I'll try that! thank you @Alexander! I'll keep you posted

Comment: I think this is fundamentally the same solution as I posted - an observation, not a criticism; you got there way before me - with perhaps with a few more optimizations, and of course you didn't operate on plain old strings. I'm pointing that out because I think a lot of what I said there also applies to this. My gut feel is that the set of map entries would not turn out to make much practical difference to simply comparing the lists, because the lists are already so small (average of ~10, according to OP), but of course you can always profile and see

Comment: Hello! So... sorry guys for waiting. I've applied your idea, making a small change to the inner loop. Because of the fact the outer list became MUCH bigger - it has 0ver 230k items. I've replaced the inner loop with a parallel stream loop. That gave a huge kick to the processing performance. For obvious reasons, I can't use parallel streams for both loops. I've also filtered items in the inner loop checking if it compares two same items '.filter(next -> !next.getBigObject().equals(wrapper.getBigObject()))' .

Comment: Anyways... I've tested that with the smaller lists first making sure it works in general. Then I tried to run it against the outer list having 232246 items in it. 
It processes it within 417912ms!!!! so less than 7 minutes! Amazing! :) I came to the fact the bigger loop of 232246 items contained about 50% duplicates. The final list has 147246 items. Obviously, that's the test data but... collected from prod DB and will be used in the future. But I'm sure it will work perfectly.

Comment: With the initial inner loop, it would take more than 4h. I've stopped it after 78k items after 1h. My PC isn't slow, I'm on AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core, got 32Gig or RAM. 
I just wanted to thank you for your efforts in helping me. You made my life easier today :) Thank you

Comment: @user007 I'm glad to know. Parallel stream is a good idea. Note that for multithreaded inviroment `boolean` flag `isDuplicate` needs to be replaced with [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to establishes a happens-before relationship.

Comment: yes! I know. I did that as well! Forgot to mention. Thank you again @AlexanderIvanchenko!

Answer (score 3):

More of a partial answer... This is the dumbest solution I could think of. I believe it's `O(N² * M)` where N is the length of the parent list, and M is the length of the sublist.

I was interested in how slow this would be. It's often a mistake to simply assume the stupid solution is going to be "too slow" without any proof.

I assumed the values in each sublist were unique - making them more like ordered sets - and played around with a pool size of possible values. Fewer possible values in the sublist = more sublists removed = faster.

On my modest CPU, for 20 possible values it takes 100ms, for 25 possible values it takes 3secs, and for 40 possible values, between 8 and 10 seconds.

Not posting this because I believe it's a good solution, but it is at least a working benchmark (as far as I know!) that a more complex solution should be surpassing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> listOfList = randomData();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Set<Integer> idxToRemove = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfList.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (idxToRemove.contains(i)) continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < listOfList.size(); ++j) {
            if (idxToRemove.contains(j)) continue;
            if (listOfList.get(i).containsAll(listOfList.get(j))) {
                idxToRemove.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
    idxToRemove.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .mapToInt(i -> i)
        .forEach(listOfList::remove);
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println(idxToRemove.size());
    System.out.println("Took " + duration + "ms");
}

private static List<List<String>> randomData() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int mainLength = 21_000;
    int possibleValues = 40;

    List<List<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<>(mainLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < mainLength; ++i) {
        int subListSize = random.nextInt(5, 20);

        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>(subListSize);
        while (subList.size() < subListSize) {
            int value = random.nextInt(possibleValues);
            if (!subList.contains(value)) {
                subList.add(value);
            }
        }
        listOfList.add(
            subList.stream().sorted().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }
    return listOfList;
}
```

Comment: It's a nice illustration. And you're right, in essence the code you've presented is very similar to mine because I was trying to optimize a brute-force algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for that Michael ... I'll compare it with the solution developed by @AlexanderIvanchenko as well.. Thank you guys.. you're helping me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would work with an algorithm like this:

1. Order the lists by their length. You can do this by assigning the inner lists to a new outer list that you sort with `Collections.sort(List<T> newOuter, Comparator<? super T> c))` with T being your inner `List<String>` and a custom Comparator that compares for the length of a list. (`String` used here only since you used that for your example, type doesn't actually matter.)
2. Start searching for the shortest list, first in the longest, then in the second longest, etc. until you can either remove the searched list or have searched all other lists. You don't have to touch that shortest list then, it will be kept. Repeat with the second shortest list, etc.

To search a list in another list:

1. Search the index of the first element of the shorter list in the longer list.
2. When you found that and the rest of the longer list is long enough to contain the shorter list, you grab a `.subList` from the longer list starting with the found index over the length of the shorter list.
3. You can then compare these lists with `.equals()` to find if the shorter list is contained within the longer one. If your inner list elements don't support `.equals()` sufficiently for this comparison, you can write your own Comparator and use that to compare the two lists.

If no match was found in step 3, you can continue searching the first element of the shorter list in the longer list. As `List.indexOf` doesn't provide a parameter at which index to start the search, probably better use a classic for-loop with an index for this. (It also would allow you to use a custom comparison if `.equals` doesn't work for you.)

To remove a list that was found within another one, you have to take care to remove it from the original outer list, not from your sorted version.

After thinking a bit about it I'm actually not so sure if starting the search in the longest list will save you time on average, due to the length of the searched list. It probably depends a bit on the distribution of lengths.

Also I would like to warn you of premature optimization: first implement a working version, then use a profiler to find the places in your code where optimization will have the biggest impact.